# Is there a way to get better information for the context of an error when using msvc? (ex: C2248)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-c++

I'm wondering if there is a way to get better information about the location of an error in msvc (2005)?

For example, when inheriting from boost::noncopyable in my class I get a C2248 error saying something like:

> error C2248: 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::noncopyable' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable'.
>   This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass &)'

but it fail to tell me where exactly the copy constructor was called. This is a little annoying. I'm really not sure but I think I remember seeing a settings somewhere where I could specify the output level or something but I searched and found nothing so my question is: Is there a way to get better (fuller?) error message in msvc?

Edit: Well since stackoverflow just told me I should look to accept an answer, I was wondering if anyone could tell if msvc 2008/2010 give a better diagnostic for this error? Someone also mentioned GCC should do, can anyone confirm this? What about other compilers (Intel?, Comeau?)

Thanks

Comment: I've run into that one before as well. Perhaps it'd be worth it to report it on connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Seems it was aldready reported and closed as wont-fix because it was judged not important enough. Thanks for the link I didn't know about this. It seems like it can be useful.

Comment: Here is the link on connect if anyone care to vote it up : https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/467747/compiler-shows-error-but-with-no-hint-to-the-users-source-code. Just had a similar problem with a missing semicolon at the end of a class definition and vs would not give me any helpfull hint in the error.

Comment: Still broken in VS20013U4. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm with Code::Blocks and VC++ 2005, that it gives no hint where the error occurs. Neither does declaring your own private copy constructor help.

```
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>

class X: boost::noncopyable
{
};

void foo(X x) {}

int main()
{

    X x;
    foo(x);
}
```

The compile log (line five is the last line of the class declaration):

> `main.cpp(5) : error C2248: 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::noncopyable' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable'
>           C:\boost_1_38_0\boost/noncopyable.hpp(27) : see declaration of 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::noncopyable'
>           C:\boost_1_38_0\boost/noncopyable.hpp(22) : see declaration of 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable'
>           This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'X::X(const X &)'`

Unless there's a compiler switch to enable more thorough error diagnostics, this wouldn't be the first time for me to simply compile the file with GCC (MinGW) to get more helpful error diagnostics. (Alas, your code should be free of VC++ extensions.)

Comment: Didn't remember that one. At least one can guess rather quick what the problem is with noncopyable.

Comment: The problem is not with noncopyable. The problem is with *your* code trying to copy something that it shouldn't be copying.

Comment: Thats what i meant. When using noncopyable you can at least figure out quickly what it means, unlike with other use-cases. There is also no useful cl.exe switch that sheds more light on this.

Comment: Well that's sad for msvc, but i'll take a look to install GCC if I can't find another workaround for my problem just to see the error message there. Congrats, you tested the solution faster than I ;o). I'll wait a day or 2 to see if other answers come in but I checked compiler options for msvc and It don't look like there is an option for better error messages so I'll probably accept your answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Of course, you could check for similar passing by value. Another thing: you don't attempt to store your noncopyable objects in a standard container?

Comment: Well in fact my problem isn't even related to the copy constructor (it's the same C2248 error though, something about attempting to access a private member) so no, but I think I will be able to solve it. Thanks for the help man.

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily create a manual copy constructor (with the same signature) and the default implementation, just for the purpose of tracking down this error..? Not sure if that would make it any easier to find.

Comment: My question is not related to this particular error. My current error is not related to a copy constructor. That was an example. Still, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the best way to workaround this (VS2013 here) seems to crawl over the output window iteratively:

1/ when you get the message "This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'X::X(const X &)'" in the output, go to your 'X' class and explicitly remove the copy constructor using the C++11 notation: "X(const X&) = delete;"

2/ recompile, now the output must display the same error but with a diagnostic occuring on child-classes, then loop again to the step 1 to explicitely delete the copy constructor on the child class, until you reach the real faulty class...

Answer (score -1):

In the output window or the build log you should see where the compiler tried to use the template in your code... you have to scroll around a bit though.

If there is not enough information in the build logs, there is also an option controlling msbuild verbosity:
Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->MSBuild project output verbosity

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly the options I was thinking about. I will try to see if it give more info and report back. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Open the output window, where the full building log is displayed. Check there the error message. Under that error message, you can usually find more information that can help you trace the source of the problem.

If you double click the problem in the error list and the go to the output window, the cursor will be positioned to that error message.

Comment: Hmm I knew I should have copy/pasted the full string so you don't think I got this from the error windows. I got this from the output windows and the only reference I got to find the error is the .cpp file where the error occured but I would like to know the location of the call to the copy constructor or any more info I can get. Thanks anyway.

Comment: With templates you usually have to scroll down past some 'noise' to get to the part where your source is mentioned.